# how can I have a custom CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter to have different layout inside my RecyclerView

Tags: android, cardslib

I'm using cardslib libarary, Is it possible to have a different layout inflated inside my CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter? I'm getting stuck at the Holder part, I'm not sure how can I do it

Comment: there is no such class in the SDK: `CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter`

Comment: I'm using a cardslib libaray

Comment: Do you want to use different layouts for each cards, or do you need  sections?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I replaced the RecyclerView with ListView and managed to do it:). However I could use it for the future, I want to add a custom pager at the begining of the list then inflate the other cards normally